# Use regex for file matching, not string matching

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, scripting, regular-expression

I'm trying to figure out how to use `grep` to search for for a specific string, (for the sake of simplicity) say `"9"`, and I want to search for this, again for simplicity, on all files containing the character `b`.

I tried `grep -e "9" b`, but it says it can't find file `b`. (The same if I don't use the `-e` option).

I know that I could go for `grep -e "9" *b*`, but that's not my point. I want the usual tools of regular expressions to use for filename matching.

I'm not interested in convoluted ways of obtaining this. I'm hoping there is a simple option in `grep` that I can use for this. I perused the `man` and I can't find anything useful, but I'm pretty new to shell scripting, so I could very easily be missing it.

Is it possible to use regular expression for filename matching using **just** `grep`? If so, how?

Comment: With the command `grep -e "9" *b*` you use usual regex to match filename (and content of the file)

Comment: @RomeoNinov "I know that I could go for `grep -e "9" *b*`, but that's not my point".  I have no reason to believe this is anything other than simply using the wildcard `*`. I'm asking about being able to use the whole typical regexs tool belt. For instance `grep -e "9" ^b*` doesn't work.

Comment: Depending on your `grep` implementation, you may be able to use its `--include` and/or `--exclude` options - however these use glob matching, rather than regular expressions

Comment: Combine it with `ls` (for example) and you can have the full spread of regex

Comment: @RomeoNinov I edited my question to eliminate that possibility. I was including that in the "convoluted ways". (Please understand that I'm not in a position to judge what's convoluted or not, given that I'm just starting with shell scripting - apologies for not being clear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in the `grep` itself to match files using regexp.

You have two options:

1. Use shell glob, like

   ```
   grep -e '9' b*
   ```

   The above is very simple example, but you can match really fancy filenames, especially if you use some of the extension mechanisms. Bellow is a list of some useful `bash`'s feature which can be switched on, similar can be found in `zsh` and possible other shells:

   - `globstar` (uses `**` to match whole directory tree)
   - `nocaseglob` (case-insensitive match)
   - `extglob` (extended patterns: `?()`, `@()`, `!()`, `*()`, `+()`)
   - `nullglob` (non-matching patterns expand to null string)
2. Use `find` to search for files and on execute `grep` from it:

   ```
   find . -name 'b*' -exec grep '9' {} +
   ```

   or if regex is needed:

   ```
   find . -regex './b.*' -exec grep '9' {} +
   ```

   The advantage of this method is that you can add another switches to `find` to select files not only by names but also by dates, sizes, etc. That cannot be done with standard shell's globs unless you are using `zsh` and its powerful *glob qualifiers*.